# Eclipse autoformat rule for putting the method call on the same line?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Currently my style is like this:

```
            UIDEx reg = sink
                    .connect(
                            urlparts[1],
                            props,
                            ClientInfo.getProperties(props
                                    .getProperty(VJdbcProperties.CLIENTINFO_PROPERTIES)),
                            new CallingContext());
```

What I actually want it to be:

```
            UIDEx reg = sink.connect(
                            urlparts[1],
                            props,
                            ClientInfo.getProperties(
                                    props.getProperty(
                                    VJdbcProperties.CLIENTINFO_PROPERTIES)),
                            new CallingContext());
```

I can't find the exact option to do that, where is it? It's already set to "wrap when necessary". How on earth does Eclipse think the .connect() needs to be on its own line?

Comment: In the `Line Wrapping > Function Calls` section, I use "Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary". That fixes it for me.

Comment: for some reason the props.getProperty(...) doesn't get wrapped, even though it's clearly more than 80 chars